# PDFBox setting A5 page size

Tags: java, pdf, apache-fop, pdfbox

Started playing with [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
document.addPage( page );

PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setFont( font, 12 );
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 100, 700 );
contentStream.drawString( "Hello World" );
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close();

document.save("Page.pdf");
document.close();
```

but I want to set the file size to be PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A5. I've tried setting all the
setXXXBox(PDRectangle mediaBox) method signatures but I can't get the expected output.

```
page.setArtBox(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A5); // ??
page.setMediaBox(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A5); // ??
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Quick note: in PDFBox 2 replace `PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A5` with `PDRectangle.A5`, i.e.

```
PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A5);
```

Answer (score 18):

Use `PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A5` to change size to A5

```
PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A5);
```

Comment: I'm using PDFBox 2.0.0-RC2 and got the same result with `PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A5)`